# Use Google Analytics with Phonegap 2.1 without a plugin?

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

I'm looking to use google analytics without a plugin with phoneGap 2.1.

I followed this thread:

[How to use Google Analytics with Phonegap without a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026916/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-phonegap-without-a-plugin)

Step:
1. download the ga.js
2. modify the ga.js file by adding one character to it. Search the ga.js file for the word "file:" and replace it with "_file:".
3. include the google analytics code in the top of your page

But it seems it doesn't work in phoneGap 2.1.

Somebody has found a solution for this problem?

Thank you

---

in my ga.js file I have "_file:",

in my index.html I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ga.js"></script>
```

and in my javascript:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36500003-1']);

_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);

_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'IpadVideos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

When I'm going in the reporting of Google, in the real time I have nobody and for my event action I have checked the next day and I have nothing...

Something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

No, I have done using it and it was working for me.
I was using phonegap 2.1 in iOS and android.

Please make sure that u have added edited ga.js in your index.html n set damain name to none.

`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);`

And it should work.

GA events are sometimes don't get registered immediately so wait for sometime and then check it.

Comment: in my ga.js file I have "_file:", 

in my index.html I have this code:

    <script  src="js/ga.js"></script> 

and in my javascript: 
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36500003-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'IpadVideos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);

When I'm going in the reporting of Google, in the real time I have nobody and for my event action I have checked the next day and I have nothing...

Something wrong in my code?

Comment: I dont find anything wrong in the code. but can u see log cats in Android their might be the issue that the domain is getting blocked. Plz see and then tell

Comment: My application is just for IOS. In fact, I have found the problem. If I put my GA code after the cordova.js the tracking doesn't work and If  my code is above it's working. It's strange because I don't have errors in the xcode console.