# Corodva 3 - How can i install GA (google analytics ) plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

How can i install GAplugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin) in Cordova 3.3 project? 
I tried with the Phonegap build way from the pluggin but neither Android nor IOS works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026916/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-phonegap-without-a-plugin check here. Your answer is here

Comment: Did you first install it through nodeJS `cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin` command?

Comment: This is the command that finally i used to install the GAplugin in cordova. Install the plugin and the appropriate libraries in the platforms and then you can use it as described in gitjub link. Thanks for your answers