# Universal Analytics for html5 embedded app

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, google-analytics

I want to track the traffic of my app, I was developed with jQueryMobile and I don't want to use the sdk for specific platforms. I will release the app for iOS, Android and Blackberry.

Thanks.

I found this, but is for the old one ga.js, and I want to use the new one analytics.js
[How to use Google Analytics with Phonegap without a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026916/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-phonegap-without-a-plugin)

Comment: And what is your question? You do understand that this is a Q/A site?

Comment: I want to use analytics.js in my html5 embedded app and I don't found how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that select "Mobile App" at create a property in Google Analytics, and to track analytics.js is necessary to select "Website"