# Google Analytics with Cordova and Framework7

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics

I'm having problems configuring google analytics with my Cordova and Framework7 application.

I have followed several tutorials and answers here on stackoverflow but nothing seems to solve my problem.

The last answer I'm using is this one here: [How to use Google Analytics with Phonegap without a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026916/how-to-use-google-analytics-with-phonegap-without-a-plugin)

So in my first row I've this:

```
<head>
  <script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>

  <script>

    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    var GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'ga:clientId';
    ga('create', 'UA-MYCODE-MC', {
      'storage': 'none',
      'clientId': localStorage.getItem(GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    });
    ga(function(tracker) {
      localStorage.setItem(GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, tracker.get('clientId'));
    });

    // THIS IS FOR FILE URL SUPPORT
    ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', function(){ /* noop */});

    // And then as usual...
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

So when I run in localhost Google Analytics seems to work fine even in real time analytics.

Once I complete the apk and install it in my phone, Google Analytics doesn't seem to receive any data from my application. 
Am I doing something wrong? Even using the Android developer tools, I don't get any console errors.

It may be related to the fact that on android the url of the app is: file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Thanks.